# How to add personal icons in MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

The Material Design Icons project contains large number of icons, but it is not enough for non English country. So how to add another pack icon in personal project without modifying Source Code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @mm8 has said, yes it's just a path; but yes, you can build your own "PackIcon" classes to follow with what you see in MaterialDesignInXaml (and MahApps) pack icons:

1: Create an Enum for each icon in your new set:

```
public enum MyPackIconKind
{
    Happy,
    Sad
}
```

2: Inherit from PackIconBase.  You must provide the path data(see note at bottom) for each icon:

```
public class MyPackIcon : PackIconBase<MyPackIconKind>
{        
    static MyPackIcon()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyPackIcon), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyPackIcon)));
    }     

    public MyPackIcon() : base(CreateIconData)
    { }

    private static IDictionary<MyPackIconKind, string> CreateIconData()
    {
        return new Dictionary<MyPackIconKind, string>
        {
            {MyPackIconKind.Happy, "M20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M10,9.5C10,10.3 9.3,11 8.5,11C7.7,11 7,10.3 7,9.5C7,8.7 7.7,8 8.5,8C9.3,8 10,8.7 10,9.5M17,9.5C17,10.3 16.3,11 15.5,11C14.7,11 14,10.3 14,9.5C14,8.7 14.7,8 15.5,8C16.3,8 17,8.7 17,9.5M12,17.23C10.25,17.23 8.71,16.5 7.81,15.42L9.23,14C9.68,14.72 10.75,15.23 12,15.23C13.25,15.23 14.32,14.72 14.77,14L16.19,15.42C15.29,16.5 13.75,17.23 12,17.23Z"},
            {MyPackIconKind.Sad, "M20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M15.5,8C16.3,8 17,8.7 17,9.5C17,10.3 16.3,11 15.5,11C14.7,11 14,10.3 14,9.5C14,8.7 14.7,8 15.5,8M10,9.5C10,10.3 9.3,11 8.5,11C7.7,11 7,10.3 7,9.5C7,8.7 7.7,8 8.5,8C9.3,8 10,8.7 10,9.5M12,14C13.75,14 15.29,14.72 16.19,15.81L14.77,17.23C14.32,16.5 13.25,16 12,16C10.75,16 9.68,16.5 9.23,17.23L7.81,15.81C8.71,14.72 10.25,14 12,14Z""}
        };
    }
}
```

3: Provide a default style (typically in your Generic.xaml), e.g:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyPackIcon}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyPackIcon}">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                        <Path Data="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"                                  
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

4: Profit!

```
<ns:MyPackIcon Kind="HappyIcon" />
```

- If path data is new to you, you can start by looking at Blend or Inkscape to save your drawings into path data format.

Comment: My svg file has several path. How can I add several path with your way?

Answer (score 3):

An Icon is basically just a `Path`:

```
<Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
    <Path Data="M9,4H15V12H19.84L12,19.84L4.16,12H9V4Z" Fill="Red" />
</Canvas>
```

You could define as many icon resources you want, for example directly in your `App.xaml` or in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Canvas x:Key="myIcon" x:Shared="False" Width="24" Height="24">
                <Path Data="M9,4H15V12H19.84L12,19.84L4.16,12H9V4Z" Fill="Red" />
            </Canvas>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

...and use them like this throughout your application:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource myIcon}" />
```