# Create a SVG File with only one path via Inkscape and use it in my WPF App - Path didnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

My goal is to create my own Icon Pack for WPF applications using the solution of James Willock ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537432/10020261 )

The two examples he uses in his code work very well. Unfortunately I can not say that from my SVG File.

The Original File is from Flaticon ( https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/gpu_1470120#term=gpu&page=1&position=2 )

Using Inkscape, I opened the file and combined the paths. This resulted in my used path.

MyPackIcon.cs

```
        private static IDictionary<MyPackIconKind, string> CreateIconData()
        {
            return new Dictionary<MyPackIconKind, string>
        {
            {MyPackIconKind.GPU, "M496,64V48c0-8.824-7.176-16-16-16H128c-8.824,0-16,7.176-16,16v16c-1.727,0-3.414,0.559-4.801,1.602L80,86V32 c0-1.574-0.473-3.129-1.344-4.441l-16-24C61.168,1.336,58.672,0,56,0H0v16h32v32H16v16h16v16H16C7.176,80,0,87.176,0,96v48 c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h16v16H16v16h16v16H16v16h16v16H16c-8.824,0-16,7.176-16,16v48c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h16v16H16v16h16v24 c0,4.414,3.586,8,8,8h16c2.672,0,5.168-1.336,6.656-3.559l16-24C79.528,355.121,80,353.574,80,352v-55.359l27,21.598 c1.426,1.145,3.184,1.762,5,1.762h16v16h-16v16h24c4.414,0,8-3.586,8-8v-24h32v16c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h16c8.824,0,16-7.176,16-16 v-16h16v16c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h128c8.824,0,16-7.176,16-16v-16h32v16c0,2.121,0.84,4.16,2.344,5.656l8,8 C443.84,351.16,445.871,352,448,352h32v-16h-28.688L448,332.688V320h48c8.824,0,16-7.176,16-16V80C512,71.176,504.824,64,496,64z  M32,304H16v-48h16V304z M32,144H16V96h16V144z M64,349.574L51.719,368H48V16h3.719L64,34.426V349.574z M128,48h352v16H128V48z  M192,336v-16h16l0.008,16H192z M496,136H378.664l-29.863-22.398C347.414,112.559,345.735,112,344,112h-56v16h53.336l29.863,22.398 c1.387,1.043,3.066,1.602,4.801,1.602h120v16h-80v16h80v16h-80v16h80v16H368c-2.129,0-4.16,0.84-5.656,2.344L340.688,256H288v16h56 c2.129,0,4.16-0.84,5.656-2.344L371.313,248H496v56H368v16h16v16H256v-16h96v-16H114.809L80,276.16V106l34.664-26H496V136z  M97.953,172.695c-0.555,2.695-0.938,5.434-1.258,8.191c-0.055,0.465-0.16,0.922-0.207,1.395C96.168,185.488,96,188.727,96,192 s0.168,6.512,0.496,9.727c0.047,0.473,0.152,0.922,0.207,1.395c0.32,2.75,0.703,5.496,1.258,8.191 c0.016,0.063,0.031,0.129,0.047,0.199c3.734,18.199,12.672,34.938,26.113,48.375c13.445,13.441,30.176,22.379,48.375,26.113 c0.063,0.016,0.129,0.031,0.199,0.047c2.695,0.555,5.434,0.938,8.191,1.258c0.465,0.055,0.922,0.16,1.395,0.207 c3.207,0.32,6.445,0.488,9.719,0.488s6.512-0.168,9.727-0.496c0.473-0.047,0.922-0.152,1.395-0.207 c2.75-0.32,5.496-0.703,8.191-1.258c0.063-0.016,0.129-0.031,0.199-0.047c18.199-3.734,34.938-12.672,48.375-26.113 c13.441-13.445,22.379-30.176,26.113-48.375c0.016-0.063,0.031-0.129,0.047-0.191c0.555-2.695,0.938-5.434,1.258-8.191 c0.055-0.465,0.16-0.922,0.207-1.395c0.32-3.215,0.488-6.453,0.488-9.727s-0.168-6.512-0.496-9.727 c-0.047-0.473-0.152-0.922-0.207-1.395c-0.32-2.75-0.703-5.496-1.258-8.191c-0.016-0.063-0.031-0.129-0.047-0.199 c-3.734-18.199-12.672-34.938-26.113-48.375c-13.445-13.441-30.176-22.379-48.375-26.113c-0.063-0.016-0.129-0.031-0.199-0.047 c-2.695-0.555-5.434-0.938-8.191-1.258c-0.465-0.055-0.922-0.16-1.395-0.207C198.512,96.168,195.274,96,192,96 s-6.512,0.168-9.727,0.496c-0.473,0.047-0.922,0.152-1.395,0.207c-2.75,0.32-5.496,0.703-8.191,1.258 c-0.063,0.016-0.129,0.031-0.199,0.047c-18.199,3.734-34.938,12.672-48.375,26.113c-13.441,13.445-22.379,30.176-26.113,48.375 C97.985,172.559,97.969,172.625,97.953,172.695z M183.992,271.602c-0.031-0.008-0.07-0.008-0.113-0.008 c-3.383-0.336-6.695-0.977-9.977-1.73c-1.078-0.246-2.141-0.527-3.199-0.824c-2.504-0.688-4.969-1.512-7.383-2.438 c-0.895-0.344-1.809-0.641-2.688-1.016c-2.777-1.188-5.465-2.578-8.098-4.082c-1.109-0.633-2.199-1.313-3.277-1.992 c-2.152-1.367-4.242-2.84-6.273-4.414c-0.52-0.41-1.074-0.77-1.586-1.188l28.531-28.527c1.941,1.289,4.008,2.344,6.125,3.266 c0.145,0.063,0.266,0.152,0.402,0.215c2.422,1.023,4.934,1.824,7.535,2.344V271.602z M241.008,255.09 c-2.023,1.582-4.121,3.055-6.266,4.422c-1.078,0.688-2.168,1.359-3.277,1.992c-2.633,1.496-5.32,2.895-8.098,4.082 c-0.879,0.375-1.793,0.672-2.688,1.016c-2.414,0.926-4.879,1.75-7.383,2.438c-1.066,0.297-2.129,0.578-3.199,0.824 c-3.281,0.754-6.594,1.395-9.977,1.73c-0.043,0.008-0.082,0-0.121,0.008v-40.402c2.594-0.527,5.113-1.328,7.535-2.344 c0.145-0.055,0.266-0.152,0.402-0.215c2.117-0.922,4.184-1.977,6.125-3.266l28.531,28.527 C242.078,254.32,241.528,254.68,241.008,255.09z M271.586,200.121c-0.34,3.383-0.969,6.703-1.73,9.984 c-0.246,1.063-0.527,2.117-0.816,3.168c-0.695,2.527-1.52,5.008-2.453,7.445c-0.328,0.855-0.609,1.738-0.969,2.578 c-1.191,2.801-2.602,5.512-4.113,8.168c-0.633,1.109-1.305,2.191-1.992,3.27c-1.367,2.152-2.84,4.25-4.422,6.273 c-0.41,0.52-0.77,1.07-1.188,1.586l-28.527-28.531c1.289-1.941,2.344-4.008,3.266-6.125c0.063-0.145,0.152-0.266,0.215-0.402 c1.023-2.422,1.824-4.934,2.344-7.535h40.395C271.594,200.039,271.594,200.078,271.586,200.121z M255.09,143 c1.582,2.023,3.055,4.121,4.422,6.273c0.68,1.078,1.352,2.16,1.992,3.27c1.512,2.648,2.922,5.352,4.113,8.16 c0.359,0.84,0.641,1.723,0.969,2.578c0.934,2.438,1.766,4.918,2.453,7.445c0.289,1.051,0.57,2.105,0.816,3.168 c0.762,3.281,1.391,6.602,1.738,9.992c0,0.043,0,0.082,0.008,0.121h-40.402c-0.527-2.594-1.328-5.113-2.344-7.535 c-0.055-0.145-0.152-0.266-0.215-0.402c-0.922-2.117-1.977-4.184-3.266-6.125l28.527-28.531 C254.321,141.93,254.68,142.48,255.09,143z M200,112.406h0.121c3.383,0.336,6.695,0.977,9.977,1.73 c1.078,0.246,2.141,0.527,3.199,0.824c2.504,0.688,4.969,1.512,7.383,2.438c0.895,0.344,1.809,0.641,2.688,1.016 c2.777,1.188,5.465,2.578,8.098,4.082c1.109,0.633,2.199,1.313,3.277,1.992c2.152,1.367,4.242,2.84,6.273,4.414 c0.52,0.41,1.074,0.77,1.586,1.188l-28.531,28.527c-1.941-1.289-4.008-2.344-6.125-3.266c-0.145-0.063-0.266-0.152-0.402-0.215 c-2.43-1.016-4.949-1.816-7.543-2.336V112.406z M187.207,168.48c1.547-0.313,3.152-0.48,4.793-0.48s3.246,0.168,4.801,0.488 c0.289,0.055,0.559,0.184,0.848,0.254c1.254,0.305,2.504,0.648,3.672,1.145c0.145,0.066,0.273,0.16,0.414,0.227 c5.402,2.414,9.746,6.75,12.16,12.16c0.066,0.141,0.16,0.27,0.227,0.414c0.496,1.168,0.832,2.418,1.145,3.672 c0.07,0.289,0.199,0.563,0.254,0.848c0.313,1.547,0.48,3.152,0.48,4.793s-0.168,3.246-0.488,4.801 c-0.063,0.297-0.191,0.566-0.266,0.863c-0.301,1.258-0.645,2.496-1.133,3.664c-0.059,0.137-0.152,0.258-0.211,0.391 c-2.414,5.434-6.781,9.801-12.223,12.211c-0.121,0.047-0.23,0.133-0.359,0.184c-1.176,0.496-2.426,0.84-3.688,1.145 c-0.289,0.07-0.555,0.191-0.84,0.254c-1.547,0.32-3.152,0.488-4.793,0.488s-3.246-0.168-4.801-0.488 c-0.297-0.055-0.559-0.184-0.848-0.254c-1.254-0.305-2.504-0.648-3.672-1.145c-0.121-0.051-0.215-0.129-0.336-0.176 c-5.473-2.418-9.863-6.809-12.281-12.281c-0.047-0.113-0.125-0.215-0.176-0.336c-0.496-1.168-0.84-2.418-1.145-3.672 c-0.07-0.289-0.199-0.559-0.254-0.848c-0.32-1.555-0.488-3.16-0.488-4.801s0.168-3.246,0.488-4.801 c0.055-0.289,0.184-0.551,0.254-0.84c0.305-1.262,0.648-2.512,1.145-3.688c0.059-0.129,0.137-0.238,0.191-0.359 c2.418-5.441,6.777-9.809,12.211-12.223c0.137-0.066,0.254-0.152,0.391-0.211c1.168-0.496,2.41-0.832,3.664-1.137 C186.641,168.672,186.91,168.543,187.207,168.48z M142.992,128.91c2.023-1.582,4.121-3.055,6.266-4.422 c1.078-0.688,2.168-1.359,3.277-1.992c2.633-1.496,5.32-2.895,8.098-4.082c0.879-0.375,1.793-0.672,2.688-1.016 c2.414-0.926,4.879-1.75,7.383-2.438c1.066-0.297,2.129-0.578,3.199-0.824c3.281-0.754,6.594-1.395,9.977-1.73 c0.043-0.008,0.082,0,0.121-0.008v40.402c-2.594,0.527-5.113,1.328-7.535,2.344c-0.145,0.055-0.266,0.152-0.402,0.215 c-2.117,0.922-4.184,1.977-6.125,3.266l-28.531-28.527C141.922,129.68,142.473,129.32,142.992,128.91z M112.414,183.879 c0.34-3.383,0.969-6.695,1.73-9.969c0.246-1.078,0.527-2.141,0.824-3.199c0.688-2.504,1.512-4.969,2.438-7.383 c0.348-0.895,0.641-1.809,1.02-2.688c1.184-2.777,2.574-5.465,4.078-8.098c0.633-1.109,1.313-2.199,1.992-3.277 c1.367-2.152,2.84-4.242,4.414-6.273c0.41-0.52,0.77-1.07,1.188-1.586l28.527,28.531c-1.289,1.941-2.344,4.008-3.266,6.125 c-0.063,0.145-0.152,0.266-0.215,0.402c-1.023,2.422-1.824,4.941-2.344,7.535h-40.395 C112.406,183.961,112.406,183.922,112.414,183.879z M152.801,200c0.527,2.594,1.328,5.113,2.344,7.535 c0.055,0.145,0.152,0.266,0.215,0.402c0.922,2.117,1.977,4.184,3.266,6.125l-28.527,28.531c-0.418-0.516-0.777-1.066-1.188-1.586 c-1.582-2.023-3.047-4.121-4.414-6.273c-0.688-1.078-1.359-2.168-1.992-3.277c-1.504-2.625-2.895-5.313-4.09-8.09 c-0.375-0.879-0.672-1.793-1.016-2.688c-0.926-2.414-1.75-4.879-2.438-7.383c-0.297-1.066-0.578-2.129-0.824-3.199 c-0.754-3.281-1.395-6.594-1.73-9.977c-0.008-0.043,0-0.082-0.008-0.121H152.801z M362.664,168H400v16h-40 c-1.734,0-3.414-0.559-4.801-1.602L325.336,160H288v-16h40c1.734,0,3.414,0.559,4.801,1.602L362.664,168z M355.199,201.602 L325.336,224H288v16h40c1.734,0,3.414-0.559,4.801-1.602L362.664,216H400v-16h-40C358.266,200,356.586,200.559,355.199,201.602z  M336,184h-32v16h32V184z M464,96v16h16V96H464z M464,288h16v-16h-16V288z " },
            {MyPackIconKind.Happy, "M20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M10,9.5C10,10.3 9.3,11 8.5,11C7.7,11 7,10.3 7,9.5C7,8.7 7.7,8 8.5,8C9.3,8 10,8.7 10,9.5M17,9.5C17,10.3 16.3,11 15.5,11C14.7,11 14,10.3 14,9.5C14,8.7 14.7,8 15.5,8C16.3,8 17,8.7 17,9.5M12,17.23C10.25,17.23 8.71,16.5 7.81,15.42L9.23,14C9.68,14.72 10.75,15.23 12,15.23C13.25,15.23 14.32,14.72 14.77,14L16.19,15.42C15.29,16.5 13.75,17.23 12,17.23Z"},
            {MyPackIconKind.Sad, "M20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M15.5,8C16.3,8 17,8.7 17,9.5C17,10.3 16.3,11 15.5,11C14.7,11 14,10.3 14,9.5C14,8.7 14.7,8 15.5,8M10,9.5C10,10.3 9.3,11 8.5,11C7.7,11 7,10.3 7,9.5C7,8.7 7.7,8 8.5,8C9.3,8 10,8.7 10,9.5M12,14C13.75,14 15.29,14.72 16.19,15.81L14.77,17.23C14.32,16.5 13.25,16 12,16C10.75,16 9.68,16.5 9.23,17.23L7.81,15.81C8.71,14.72 10.25,14 12,14Z"},
        };
        }
```

And here is my MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <icons:MyPackIcon Kind="GPU" Foreground="White" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="100 0 0 0"/>
            <icons:MyPackIcon Kind="Happy" Foreground="White" Height="50" Width="50"/>
            <icons:MyPackIcon Kind="Sad" Foreground="White" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

The example paths are displayed in the correct size. The path from my SVG does not pay attention to the height or width which I indicated. And this is my Problem, I dont know what I am doing wrong with my GPU SVG

https://i.stack.imgur.com/428SP.jpg

Comment: Put your path in a viewbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend putting paths in viewboxes as they will otherwise never be the size you want them to be (in your case its a coincidence i guess)

```
<ViewBox Height="50" Width="50" Margin="100 0 0 0">
  <Path Data=“M496,64V48c0-8.824-7.176-16-16-16H128c-8.824,0-16,7.176-16,16v16c-1.727,0-3.414,0.559-4.801,1.602L80,86V32 c0-1.574-0.473-3.129-1.344-4.441l-16-24C61.168,1.336,58.672,0,56,0H0v16h32v32H16v16h16v16H16C7.176,80,0,87.176,0,96v48 c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h16v16H16v16h16v16H16v16h16v16H16c-8.824,0-16,7.176-16,16v48c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h16v16H16v16h16v24 c0,4.414,3.586,8,8,8h16c2.672,0,5.168-1.336,6.656-3.559l16-24C79.528,355.121,80,353.574,80,352v-55.359l27,21.598 c1.426,1.145,3.184,1.762,5,1.762h16v16h-16v16h24c4.414,0,8-3.586,8-8v-24h32v16c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h16c8.824,0,16-7.176,16-16 v-16h16v16c0,8.824,7.176,16,16,16h128c8.824,0,16-7.176,16-16v-16h32v16c0,2.121,0.84,4.16,2.344,5.656l8,8 C443.84,351.16,445.871,352,448,352h32v-16h-28.688L448,332.688V320h48c8.824,0,16-7.176,16-16V80C512,71.176,504.824,64,496,64z  M32,304H16v-48h16V304z M32,144H16V96h16V144z M64,349.574L51.719,368H48V16h3.719L64,34.426V349.574z M128,48h352v16H128V48z  M192,336v-16h16l0.008,16H192z M496,136H378.664l-29.863-22.398C347.414,112.559,345.735,112,344,112h-56v16h53.336l29.863,22.398 c1.387,1.043,3.066,1.602,4.801,1.602h120v16h-80v16h80v16h-80v16h80v16H368c-2.129,0-4.16,0.84-5.656,2.344L340.688,256H288v16h56 c2.129,0,4.16-0.84,5.656-2.344L371.313,248H496v56H368v16h16v16H256v-16h96v-16H114.809L80,276.16V106l34.664-26H496V136z  M97.953,172.695c-0.555,2.695-0.938,5.434-1.258,8.191c-0.055,0.465-0.16,0.922-0.207,1.395C96.168,185.488,96,188.727,96,192 s0.168,6.512,0.496,9.727c0.047,0.473,0.152,0.922,0.207,1.395c0.32,2.75,0.703,5.496,1.258,8.191 c0.016,0.063,0.031,0.129,0.047,0.199c3.734,18.199,12.672,34.938,26.113,48.375c13.445,13.441,30.176,22.379,48.375,26.113 c0.063,0.016,0.129,0.031,0.199,0.047c2.695,0.555,5.434,0.938,8.191,1.258c0.465,0.055,0.922,0.16,1.395,0.207 c3.207,0.32,6.445,0.488,9.719,0.488s6.512-0.168,9.727-0.496c0.473-0.047,0.922-0.152,1.395-0.207 c2.75-0.32,5.496-0.703,8.191-1.258c0.063-0.016,0.129-0.031,0.199-0.047c18.199-3.734,34.938-12.672,48.375-26.113 c13.441-13.445,22.379-30.176,26.113-48.375c0.016-0.063,0.031-0.129,0.047-0.191c0.555-2.695,0.938-5.434,1.258-8.191 c0.055-0.465,0.16-0.922,0.207-1.395c0.32-3.215,0.488-6.453,0.488-9.727s-0.168-6.512-0.496-9.727 c-0.047-0.473-0.152-0.922-0.207-1.395c-0.32-2.75-0.703-5.496-1.258-8.191c-0.016-0.063-0.031-0.129-0.047-0.199 c-3.734-18.199-12.672-34.938-26.113-48.375c-13.445-13.441-30.176-22.379-48.375-26.113c-0.063-0.016-0.129-0.031-0.199-0.047 c-2.695-0.555-5.434-0.938-8.191-1.258c-0.465-0.055-0.922-0.16-1.395-0.207C198.512,96.168,195.274,96,192,96 s-6.512,0.168-9.727,0.496c-0.473,0.047-0.922,0.152-1.395,0.207c-2.75,0.32-5.496,0.703-8.191,1.258 c-0.063,0.016-0.129,0.031-0.199,0.047c-18.199,3.734-34.938,12.672-48.375,26.113c-13.441,13.445-22.379,30.176-26.113,48.375 C97.985,172.559,97.969,172.625,97.953,172.695z M183.992,271.602c-0.031-0.008-0.07-0.008-0.113-0.008 c-3.383-0.336-6.695-0.977-9.977-1.73c-1.078-0.246-2.141-0.527-3.199-0.824c-2.504-0.688-4.969-1.512-7.383-2.438 c-0.895-0.344-1.809-0.641-2.688-1.016c-2.777-1.188-5.465-2.578-8.098-4.082c-1.109-0.633-2.199-1.313-3.277-1.992 c-2.152-1.367-4.242-2.84-6.273-4.414c-0.52-0.41-1.074-0.77-1.586-1.188l28.531-28.527c1.941,1.289,4.008,2.344,6.125,3.266 c0.145,0.063,0.266,0.152,0.402,0.215c2.422,1.023,4.934,1.824,7.535,2.344V271.602z M241.008,255.09 c-2.023,1.582-4.121,3.055-6.266,4.422c-1.078,0.688-2.168,1.359-3.277,1.992c-2.633,1.496-5.32,2.895-8.098,4.082 c-0.879,0.375-1.793,0.672-2.688,1.016c-2.414,0.926-4.879,1.75-7.383,2.438c-1.066,0.297-2.129,0.578-3.199,0.824 c-3.281,0.754-6.594,1.395-9.977,1.73c-0.043,0.008-0.082,0-0.121,0.008v-40.402c2.594-0.527,5.113-1.328,7.535-2.344 c0.145-0.055,0.266-0.152,0.402-0.215c2.117-0.922,4.184-1.977,6.125-3.266l28.531,28.527 C242.078,254.32,241.528,254.68,241.008,255.09z M271.586,200.121c-0.34,3.383-0.969,6.703-1.73,9.984 c-0.246,1.063-0.527,2.117-0.816,3.168c-0.695,2.527-1.52,5.008-2.453,7.445c-0.328,0.855-0.609,1.738-0.969,2.578 c-1.191,2.801-2.602,5.512-4.113,8.168c-0.633,1.109-1.305,2.191-1.992,3.27c-1.367,2.152-2.84,4.25-4.422,6.273 c-0.41,0.52-0.77,1.07-1.188,1.586l-28.527-28.531c1.289-1.941,2.344-4.008,3.266-6.125c0.063-0.145,0.152-0.266,0.215-0.402 c1.023-2.422,1.824-4.934,2.344-7.535h40.395C271.594,200.039,271.594,200.078,271.586,200.121z M255.09,143 c1.582,2.023,3.055,4.121,4.422,6.273c0.68,1.078,1.352,2.16,1.992,3.27c1.512,2.648,2.922,5.352,4.113,8.16 c0.359,0.84,0.641,1.723,0.969,2.578c0.934,2.438,1.766,4.918,2.453,7.445c0.289,1.051,0.57,2.105,0.816,3.168 c0.762,3.281,1.391,6.602,1.738,9.992c0,0.043,0,0.082,0.008,0.121h-40.402c-0.527-2.594-1.328-5.113-2.344-7.535 c-0.055-0.145-0.152-0.266-0.215-0.402c-0.922-2.117-1.977-4.184-3.266-6.125l28.527-28.531 C254.321,141.93,254.68,142.48,255.09,143z M200,112.406h0.121c3.383,0.336,6.695,0.977,9.977,1.73 c1.078,0.246,2.141,0.527,3.199,0.824c2.504,0.688,4.969,1.512,7.383,2.438c0.895,0.344,1.809,0.641,2.688,1.016 c2.777,1.188,5.465,2.578,8.098,4.082c1.109,0.633,2.199,1.313,3.277,1.992c2.152,1.367,4.242,2.84,6.273,4.414 c0.52,0.41,1.074,0.77,1.586,1.188l-28.531,28.527c-1.941-1.289-4.008-2.344-6.125-3.266c-0.145-0.063-0.266-0.152-0.402-0.215 c-2.43-1.016-4.949-1.816-7.543-2.336V112.406z M187.207,168.48c1.547-0.313,3.152-0.48,4.793-0.48s3.246,0.168,4.801,0.488 c0.289,0.055,0.559,0.184,0.848,0.254c1.254,0.305,2.504,0.648,3.672,1.145c0.145,0.066,0.273,0.16,0.414,0.227 c5.402,2.414,9.746,6.75,12.16,12.16c0.066,0.141,0.16,0.27,0.227,0.414c0.496,1.168,0.832,2.418,1.145,3.672 c0.07,0.289,0.199,0.563,0.254,0.848c0.313,1.547,0.48,3.152,0.48,4.793s-0.168,3.246-0.488,4.801 c-0.063,0.297-0.191,0.566-0.266,0.863c-0.301,1.258-0.645,2.496-1.133,3.664c-0.059,0.137-0.152,0.258-0.211,0.391 c-2.414,5.434-6.781,9.801-12.223,12.211c-0.121,0.047-0.23,0.133-0.359,0.184c-1.176,0.496-2.426,0.84-3.688,1.145 c-0.289,0.07-0.555,0.191-0.84,0.254c-1.547,0.32-3.152,0.488-4.793,0.488s-3.246-0.168-4.801-0.488 c-0.297-0.055-0.559-0.184-0.848-0.254c-1.254-0.305-2.504-0.648-3.672-1.145c-0.121-0.051-0.215-0.129-0.336-0.176 c-5.473-2.418-9.863-6.809-12.281-12.281c-0.047-0.113-0.125-0.215-0.176-0.336c-0.496-1.168-0.84-2.418-1.145-3.672 c-0.07-0.289-0.199-0.559-0.254-0.848c-0.32-1.555-0.488-3.16-0.488-4.801s0.168-3.246,0.488-4.801 c0.055-0.289,0.184-0.551,0.254-0.84c0.305-1.262,0.648-2.512,1.145-3.688c0.059-0.129,0.137-0.238,0.191-0.359 c2.418-5.441,6.777-9.809,12.211-12.223c0.137-0.066,0.254-0.152,0.391-0.211c1.168-0.496,2.41-0.832,3.664-1.137 C186.641,168.672,186.91,168.543,187.207,168.48z M142.992,128.91c2.023-1.582,4.121-3.055,6.266-4.422 c1.078-0.688,2.168-1.359,3.277-1.992c2.633-1.496,5.32-2.895,8.098-4.082c0.879-0.375,1.793-0.672,2.688-1.016 c2.414-0.926,4.879-1.75,7.383-2.438c1.066-0.297,2.129-0.578,3.199-0.824c3.281-0.754,6.594-1.395,9.977-1.73 c0.043-0.008,0.082,0,0.121-0.008v40.402c-2.594,0.527-5.113,1.328-7.535,2.344c-0.145,0.055-0.266,0.152-0.402,0.215 c-2.117,0.922-4.184,1.977-6.125,3.266l-28.531-28.527C141.922,129.68,142.473,129.32,142.992,128.91z M112.414,183.879 c0.34-3.383,0.969-6.695,1.73-9.969c0.246-1.078,0.527-2.141,0.824-3.199c0.688-2.504,1.512-4.969,2.438-7.383 c0.348-0.895,0.641-1.809,1.02-2.688c1.184-2.777,2.574-5.465,4.078-8.098c0.633-1.109,1.313-2.199,1.992-3.277 c1.367-2.152,2.84-4.242,4.414-6.273c0.41-0.52,0.77-1.07,1.188-1.586l28.527,28.531c-1.289,1.941-2.344,4.008-3.266,6.125 c-0.063,0.145-0.152,0.266-0.215,0.402c-1.023,2.422-1.824,4.941-2.344,7.535h-40.395 C112.406,183.961,112.406,183.922,112.414,183.879z M152.801,200c0.527,2.594,1.328,5.113,2.344,7.535 c0.055,0.145,0.152,0.266,0.215,0.402c0.922,2.117,1.977,4.184,3.266,6.125l-28.527,28.531c-0.418-0.516-0.777-1.066-1.188-1.586 c-1.582-2.023-3.047-4.121-4.414-6.273c-0.688-1.078-1.359-2.168-1.992-3.277c-1.504-2.625-2.895-5.313-4.09-8.09 c-0.375-0.879-0.672-1.793-1.016-2.688c-0.926-2.414-1.75-4.879-2.438-7.383c-0.297-1.066-0.578-2.129-0.824-3.199 c-0.754-3.281-1.395-6.594-1.73-9.977c-0.008-0.043,0-0.082-0.008-0.121H152.801z M362.664,168H400v16h-40 c-1.734,0-3.414-0.559-4.801-1.602L325.336,160H288v-16h40c1.734,0,3.414,0.559,4.801,1.602L362.664,168z M355.199,201.602 L325.336,224H288v16h40c1.734,0,3.414-0.559,4.801-1.602L362.664,216H400v-16h-40C358.266,200,356.586,200.559,355.199,201.602z  M336,184h-32v16h32V184z M464,96v16h16V96H464z M464,288h16v-16h-16V288z”/>    
</ViewBox>
```

EDIT:
If you want to stick with your appoach all you need to do is this in your style:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyPackIcon}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyPackIcon}">
                <Grid> 
                    <Viewbox Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Path Data="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"                                  
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This seems not correct. All Default Icons working well without ViewBox and ViewBox doesnt change anything in my GPU icon, I tried it. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Edited my answer it will work with a path so you need to modify the icon control

Comment: To create an iconcollectoon i recommend putting the code above in a custom control and binding its data to a dependency property you bind to also adding templatebindings for the viewbox height and witdh.  now you can create you path data in a static resscource and use it

Comment: Please let me know if that fixed your issue

Comment: If it solved your issue please mark it as answer for others to find

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make those geometry rather than string.

If you just set the data of a path to a geometry then you will get the original size defined by the geometry co-ordinates.

To avoid that, set the stretch property of your path to fill or uniform.

It will fill whatever container it's in if you don't set size.

No viewbox or canvas necessary.

The way i usually do this sort of thing is to define a number of geometries in a resource dictionary. obviously, give each an x:key. and set the data of a path using one as a staticresource.

Answer (score 0):

The other question, that you link to, has paths with small coordinate values.  Ie. all less than the `16` that is specified in his XAML file.

However your paths have large coordinate values.  For instance, the first move (M) command is to `496,64`.

If you want to produce icons of a matching size to the earlier ones.  You should try changing the document size in Inkscape to 16x16 px.

File -> Document Properties -> Custom size

And resize your graphics down to fit that size.